# Reasons to transition Kerberos secured web applications to OAuth2/OpenId

Tags: java, oauth2, kerberos, aws

We have five internal web applications written in Java  / AngularJs that are secured via Kerberos/ Spnego ( Spring Security implementation) . We are looking to transition these apps to AWS ( EBS) .

I am building a business case to convince the management why I should rewrite the auth. on these apps to use OAuth2/OpenId . Looks like Kerberos is supported via Amazon EMR.. or at the worst we just provision another EC2 with a domain controller.  What are my considerations , pros and cons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pros;

- oauth works from computers not in your domain.

cons;

- oauth works from computers not in your domain
- extra development work
- need to login to more than just the OS.

Comment: why is computers not in your domain a benefit ?   Does SAML have the same benefits?

Comment: @JavaHead it just depends on your usage requirements. SAML is about the same as OAuth for this comparison.